# Application-defined or object-defined error while trying to copy data

Tags: excel, vba

I copied a script to a command button (even tried retyping it). The previous script is works fine, but moves through several other unrelated steps as well.

I wanted to set up a macro to run through a command button in order to just update the data in the table. For some reason though, I receive a compile error: Variable required - can't assign to this expression.
The error occurs at: `ReportWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, shtc), Cells(1000, shtc)).Copy` (line 28)

The objective of the file is to determine the column that is relevant to what data it needs to extract, copy and then paste it. This is the script. What am I missing?

```
Option Explicit

Dim ReportWbk As Workbook 'workbook with report data
Dim Report As String 'name of file with report data
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim shtc As Integer, ttl As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error goto here

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).Show
    Report = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).SelectedItems(1)
    Set ReportWbk = Workbooks.Open(Report)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    shtc = 1
    While ReportWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, shtc) <> "Name"
        shtc = shtc + 1
    Wend

    ttl = 1
    While ReportWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, ttl) <> "Val.in rep.cur."
        ttl = ttl + 1
    Wend

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a2:b1000").ClearContents
    ReportWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ReportWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, shtc), Cells(1000, shtc)).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1).Select: Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1).Select

    ReportWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ReportWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, ttl), Cells(1000, ttl)).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2).Select: Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2).Select

    ReportWbk.Close (False)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    With CommandButton1
        .AutoSize = False
        .AutoSize = True
        .Height = 40
        .Left = 435
        .Width = 200
        .Top = 12
    End With


Exit Sub

here:
    MsgBox ("Select the correct file!")
    ReportWbk.Close (False)
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Add the `ReportWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").` before `Cells()` in the `Range()`.  It's a little unintuitive, but even when you specify which workbook and sheet a `Range()` is on, if you use `Cells()` in that `Range()`, you'll need to also specify.

Comment: Made the adjustment, the script still gets hung up, two lines before that instance (the `.copy` line)

Comment: There's two instances of that. Which line, specifically, is the one that is throwing you into debug now?

Comment: The very first one. with that, it stands to reason it will do the same if it even makes it to the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little refactoring:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const NUM_ROWS As Long = 1000 'number of rows to copy
    Dim shtRpt As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, shtc As Long, ttl As Long, Report
    Dim ReportWbk As Workbook

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).Show
    Report = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).SelectedItems(1)

    Set ReportWbk = Workbooks.Open(Report)
    Set shtRpt = ReportWbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    'find the header columns
    shtc = GetColumn(shtRpt.Rows(1), "Name")
    ttl = GetColumn(shtRpt.Rows(1), "Val.in rep.cur.")

    'missing columns ?
    If shtc = 0 Or ttl = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Select the correct file!", vbExclamation
        ReportWbk.Close False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sht2.Range("A2").Resize(NUM_ROWS, 1).Value = _
                   shtRpt.Cells(2, shtc).Resize(NUM_ROWS, 1).Value
    sht2.Range("B2").Resize(NUM_ROWS, 1).Value = _
                   shtRpt.Cells(2, ttl).Resize(NUM_ROWS, 1).Value


    ReportWbk.Close (False)

    With CommandButton1
        .AutoSize = False
        .AutoSize = True
        .Height = 40
        .Left = 435
        .Width = 200
        .Top = 12
    End With

End Sub

'get the column number for specified content
'  return zero if not found
Function GetColumn(rng As Range, hdr) As Long
    Dim f As Range, rv As Long
    rv = 0
    Set f = rng.Find(hdr, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then rv = f.Column
    GetColumn = rv
End Function
```

Comment: hmmm I tried using this script, and it returns a compile error on the first `GetColumn`. `Compile error: Sub or Function not defined`

Comment: Did you add the `GetColumn` function?

Comment: Whoops, in my haste, I somehow missed it. Works perfectly!